# How retrieve database value in text box by select item in drop down list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to fill text box value in `asp.net` but when I choose item in drop down list the item of drop down list contains `id` and `name` of users in database SQL sever, and when I click on item I want to retrieve value of this user in text box .

Comment: value of user means??

Comment: You mean you want details of user as per the user id which u have in dropdown??

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to listen for an on change event on your drop-down select list, and then update you input text field accordingly:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("inpTxt");
var sel = document.getElementById("inpSel");

sel.addEventListener("change", function() {
  txt.value = sel.value;
});
```

```html
<select id="inpSel">
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="inpTxt">
```